# Alinhar row no fundo de uma section

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Queria alinhar uma row de Bootstrap 3 contida num `container-fluid` no fundo de uma section da minha página.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso sem recorrer a javascript?

Pensei que poderia colocar a row com posição absoluta, mas depois deixaria de funcionar para as restantes secções desta forma.

Answer (score 1):

Se você usar posicionamento absoluto, dentro de um elemento com posicionamento relativo, então vai funcionar. No caso, sua *row* específica teria `position: absolute` e sua *section* teria `position: relative`.

Exemplo:

```css
.conteiner {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.para-o-fundo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner" style="background: green;">
    contêinero, com <em>position: relative</em>
    <div class="para-o-fundo">Texto no fundo, com <em>position: absolute</em></div>
</div>
<div class="conteiner" style="background: red;">
    contêiner
    <div class="para-o-fundo">Texto no fundo</div>
</div>
<div class="conteiner" style="background: yellow;">
    contêiner
    <div class="para-o-fundo">Texto no fundo</div>
</div>
```

O posicionamento `absolute`, é sempre em relação ao primeiro elemento ancestral, que tenha por sua vez o posicionamento definido como `absolute`, `fixed` ou `relative`.

[Leia mais sobre isso no css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)<sup>(em Inglês)</sup>